# Method should return array containing all strings shorter than 6 characters or begin with e

Tags: javascript, string, methods, numbers

Write a method `strange_words` that accept an array of strings
The method should return an array containing all strings that are either shorter than 6 characters or begin with "e"

```
    function strangeWords(words){
      //write your code here
     }
   function printStringArray(strings){
 if(strings.length===0){
   console.log('[]');
  }else{
   console.log(`[${strings.join(',')}]`);
   }
   }
 printStringArray(strangeWords(["taco","eggs","excellent","exponential","artistic","cat","eat"]))
```

Comment: You need to include a statement/explanation of the problem with your code. This means more than just "it's not working" as that could mean multiple things. Also note SO is not a place for writing code for you we are here to help with code you are writing yourself and solving a problem you encounter doing so

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` to return the strings which satisfy the condition

```js
function printStringArray(strings){
  return strings.filter((str) => str.length <= 6 || str.startsWith('e'));
}

console.log(printStringArray(["taco","eggs","excellent","exponential","artistic","cat","eat"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`, and check if the `length` is less than 6, or if the string's first character is an `e`:

```js
function strangeWords(words) {
  return words.filter(w => w.length < 6 || w.toLowerCase()[0] == "e");
}

console.log(strangeWords(["taco", "eggs", "excellent", "exponential", "artistic", "cat", "eat"]));
```

Comment: OP said : _The method should return an array containing all strings that are either **shorter than 6** characters or begin with "e"_

Comment: Whoops, my bad @MaheerAli.

Answer (score 0):

```
function strangeWords(words) {
  return words.filter(word => (word.length < 6 || word.search(/^[eE].*/)));
}

console.log(strangeWords(["taco", "eggs", "excellent", "exponential", "artistic", "cat", "eat"]));
```